# Bootstrap 4 collapsing vertical menu on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to create the collapsing vertical menu on the right just like on this website: http://presentation.creative-tim.com/

You can see the source code: view-source:http://presentation.creative-tim.com/

This is my current state of the website:

[image]

I want the same effect. When I click on the third icon (menu icon), I want to create a menu on the right that has items.
Currently, it is set on the default collapse menu: 
[image]

While I want to be like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this, what is the name of this effect ?

This is my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/n12o3vhz/

Here is the navbar only:

```
        <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-burger">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                            <i class="material-icons md-36">shopping_cart</i>
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="prakse.html">
                            <i class="material-icons md-36">search</i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">
                            <i class="material-icons md-36">menu</i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap v4.1.0 & jQuery 3.3.1